# SQL Query that checks the no of occurances in a table column based on a reference column

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables called contract and contractrecords. For every contract there will be multiple contractrecords, that means contractid will be the foriegnkey reference in contractrecords. There is a status column in the contractrecords and it might have the values of 1,2,3,4.
Now my problem is if a contract has multiple contractrecords and all of them has the status 1 then the contract is active. If all the contractrecords have the status other than 1, then contract is inactive. If atleast one contractrecord has the status 1 then that contract is partialactive.

How to achive this?

Comment: Google and learn about the EXISTS() function in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
Select contractId, 
     status = case when total = status then 'active'
         when status = 0 then 'inactive'
         else 'partial'
     end
From (
    Select contractId, total = count(recordId), status = Sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0)
    From contractrecords
    Group By contractId
)
```

Update with your tables and columns (and fix typo perhaps)